# Deserialize json array stream one item at a time

Tags: c#, json, serialization, stream, json.net

I serialize an array of large objects to a json http response stream. Now I want to deserialize these objects from the stream one at a time. Are there any c# libraries that will let me do this? I've looked at json.net but it seems I'd have to deserialize the complete array of objects at once.

```
[{large json object},{large json object}.....]
```

Clarification: I want to read one json object from the stream at a time and deserialize it.

Comment: Why exactly do you want such a behavior?

Comment: Because I don't want to keep the entire array of large objects in memory.

Comment: You'll probably need to use `JsonTextReader` from Json.NET and read the tokens in manually.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In order to read the JSON incrementally, you'll need to use a `JsonTextReader` in combination with a `StreamReader`.  But, you don't necessarily have to read all the JSON manually from the reader.  You should be able to leverage the Linq-To-JSON API to load each large object from the reader so that you can work with it more easily.

For a simple example, say I had a JSON file that looked like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "baz",
    "id": 3
  }
]
```

Code to read it incrementally from the file might look something like the following.  (In your case you would replace the FileStream with your response stream.)

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\data.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            // Load each object from the stream and do something with it
            JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(obj["id"] + " - " + obj["name"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the above would look like this:

```
1 - foo
2 - bar
3 - baz
```

Comment: This is essentially the same solution I came up with. Except I do a new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<T>(reader); instead of JObject.Load. I'm not exactly sure how JsonTextReader manages the stream data though.

Comment: You can always peruse the [source code](http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs) to find out.

Comment: this got me going in the right direction, but i had to do `JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize<T>(reader, desiredType);` since `JObject.Load` never worked (nor threw an error -- it was most bizarre).

Comment: Remember, using JObject.Load is not performant compared to serializer.Deserialize. So always use Deserialize

Answer (score 4):

I have simplified one of the samples/tests of my parser/deserializer to answer this question's use case more straightforwardly.

Here's for the test data:

https://github.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser/tree/master/JsonTest/TestData

(cf. fathers.json.txt)

And here's for the sample code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    // Our stuff
    using System.Text.Json;

//...

    public class FathersData
    {
        public Father[] fathers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Someone
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Father : Someone
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool married { get; set; }
        // Lists...
        public List<Son> sons { get; set; }
        // ... or arrays for collections, that's fine:
        public Daughter[] daughters { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child : Someone
    {
        public int age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Son : Child
    {
    }

    public class Daughter : Child
    {
        public string maidenName { get; set; }
    }

//...

    static void FilteredFatherStreamTestSimplified()
    {
        // Get our parser:
        var parser = new JsonParser();

        // (Note this will be invoked thanks to the "filters" dictionary below)
        Func<object, object> filteredFatherStreamCallback = obj =>
        {
            Father father = (obj as Father);
            // Output only the individual fathers that the filters decided to keep (i.e., when obj.Type equals typeof(Father)),
            // but don't output (even once) the resulting array (i.e., when obj.Type equals typeof(Father[])):
            if (father != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tId : {0}\t\tName : {1}", father.id, father.name);
            }
            // Do not project the filtered data in any specific way otherwise,
            // just return it deserialized as-is:
            return obj;
        };

        // Prepare our filter, and thus:
        // 1) we want only the last five (5) fathers (array index in the resulting "Father[]" >= 29,995),
        // (assuming we somehow have prior knowledge that the total count is 30,000)
        // and for each of them,
        // 2) we're interested in deserializing them with only their "id" and "name" properties
        var filters = 
            new Dictionary<Type, Func<Type, object, object, int, Func<object, object>>>
            {
                // We don't care about anything but these 2 properties:
                {
                    typeof(Father), // Note the type
                    (type, obj, key, index) =>
                        ((key as string) == "id" || (key as string) == "name") ?
                        filteredFatherStreamCallback :
                        JsonParser.Skip
                },
                // We want to pick only the last 5 fathers from the source:
                {
                    typeof(Father[]), // Note the type
                    (type, obj, key, index) =>
                        (index >= 29995) ?
                        filteredFatherStreamCallback :
                        JsonParser.Skip
                }
            };

        // Read, parse, and deserialize fathers.json.txt in a streamed fashion,
        // and using the above filters, along with the callback we've set up:
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(FATHERS_TEST_FILE_PATH))
        {
            FathersData data = parser.Parse<FathersData>(reader, filters);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert
            (
                (data != null) &&
                (data.fathers != null) &&
                (data.fathers.Length == 5)
            );
            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(29995, 5))
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert
                (
                    (data.fathers[i - 29995].id == i) &&
                    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.fathers[i - 29995].name)
                );
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The rest of the bits is available here:

https://github.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser

'HTH,

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old, but it appears in google search, and I needed the same thing recently. The another way to deal with stream serilization is to use [JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasyncenumerable?view=net-7.0)

Usage looks like:

```
await using (var readStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    await foreach (T item in JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<T>(readStream))
    {                        
        // do something withe the item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (combined from different sources, but mainly based on [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers) solution) to convert huge JSON file (which is an array of objects) to XML file for any generic object.

JSON looks like this:

```
   {
      "Order": [
          { order object 1},
          { order object 2},
          {...}
          { order object 10000},
      ]
   }
```

Output XML:

```
<Order>...</Order>
<Order>...</Order>
<Order>...</Order>
```

C# code:

```
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(xmlFile))
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(jsonFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    //sw.Write("<root>");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
                    XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(obj.ToString(), "Order");
                    sw.Write(doc.InnerXml); // a line of XML code <Order>...</Order>
                    sw.Write("\n");
                    //this approach produces not strictly valid XML document
                    //add root element at the beginning and at the end to make it valid XML                                
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //sw.Write("</root>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library, you can parse large JSON efficiently with low memory footprint. Since the objects are constructed and returned in a stream based pull model

```
using (var p = new ChoJSONReader(** YOUR JSON FILE **))
{
            foreach (var rec in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {rec.name}, Id: {rec.id}");
            }
}
```

For more information, please visit codeproject article.

Hope it helps.