# System.OutOfMemoryException with JSON.NET with List<object>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I'm doing a process where my server generates a file with JSON.Net with 25000 records and size of 85MB, then this file is imported by client.

The client downloads the file and makes the deserialize with JSON.Net.

My problem is that the times and on different machines, deserialize command is giving:

`System.OutOfMemoryException`

Note: I tried to manually use the GC did not work.

#### Code generate error:

```
var listAddress = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<address>>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Temp\test.json");
```

#### Code generate JSON File:

```
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText("C:\\test.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();                        
    serializer.Serialize(file, listAddress);                        
}
```

#### My Class Address

```
public class Endereco
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string CGCCPF { get; set; }
    public char? TipoPessoa { get; set; }
    public string UF { get; set; }
    public string SiglaDoRG { get; set; }
    public string MaeFantasica { get; set; }
    public string DescEndereco { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string CEP { get; set; }
    public string Pai { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string IEouRG { get; set; }
    public string OrgaoEmissorRG { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public CampoObservacao Observacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataRegistro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataUltAlteracao { get; set; }
    public int? CodigoFuncionario { get; set; }
    public string Ramal { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataDeEmissaoRG { get; set; }
    public string Alfa1 { get; set; }
    public string Alfa2 { get; set; }
    public double? Num1 { get; set; }
    public double? Num2 { get; set; }
    public string PontoReferencia { get; set; }
    public string Celular { get; set; }
    public string EnderecoWeb { get; set; }
    public string Conta { get; set; }
    public string Rasocial { get; set; }
    public int? NcCodigo { get; set; }
    public int? NcCodigoC { get; set; }
    public string CFOP { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public int? CodigoMunicipio { get; set; }
    public int? CodigoPais { get; set; }
    public string Suframa { get; set; }
    public string NumeroNit { get; set; }
    public string InscricaoMunicipal { get; set; }
    public string IE { get; set; }

    public bool Ativo
    {
        get { return !Observacao["Status"].Equals("I"); }
        set { Observacao["Status"] = !value ? "I" : String.Empty; }
    }

    public Endereco()
    {
        Observacao = new CampoObservacao();
    }

    public char? TipoDeMercado
    {
        get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Observacao["Tipo de Mercado"]) ? (char?)Observacao["Tipo de Mercado"][0] : null; }
        set { Observacao["Tipo de Mercado"] = value.HasValue ? value.ToString() : String.Empty; }
    }

    public char? EstadoCivil
    {
        get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Observacao["EstadoCivil"]) ? (char?)Observacao["EstadoCivil"][0] : null; }
        set { Observacao["EstadoCivil"] = value.HasValue ? value.ToString() : String.Empty; }
    }

    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public Funcionario Funcionario { get; set; }
    public Filial Filial { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you use [streaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157636/can-json-net-serialize-deserialize-to-from-a-stream)?

Comment: @CodeCaster Where? To generate the file?

Comment: Could. But I can not do. Would have an example? @CodeCaster

Comment: Click the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157636/can-json-net-serialize-deserialize-to-from-a-stream).

Comment: I will test and look for stream file. tks @CodeCaster

Comment: Have you tried deserializing one of the failing files in your dev environment? It could be the file contents that is causing the error.

Comment: I have 5 files for this process. But they fail in different situations and in different files. Sometimes the first file, as happened in the fourth and then the fifth. @ShellShock

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserialize json array stream one item at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374083/deserialize-json-array-stream-one-item-at-a-time)

Comment: Any chance of changing the server to return a sane format like CSV? If so, you'll dramatically cut down on the size of your file and even naïve CSV parsers are faster than JSON parsers.

Answer (score 3):

I was playing around a bit with the answer linked above: [Deserialize json array stream one item at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374083/deserialize-json-array-stream-one-item-at-a-time/20386292#20386292).  The following slight modification might meet your needs.  It reads and deserializes the JSON item-by-item rather than loading the entire list into memory:

```
public static class JsonConvertExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeEnumerableFile<T>(string filename)
    {
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(filename))
            foreach (var item in DeserializeEnumerable<T>(stream))
                yield return item;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeEnumerableString<T>(string json)
    {
        using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
            foreach (var item in DeserializeEnumerable<T>(sr))
                yield return item;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeEnumerable<T>(TextReader textReader)
    {
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();

        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    // Load each object from the stream and do something with it
                    yield return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```