# OutOfMemoryException when reading a string

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a C# .NET system that takes a `JSON` data feed and converts it to an object using the `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` converter.

This process works perfect as long as the JSON string is below a certain size (a few Mb) but as soon as the returned data is large (almost 100Mb) I get the error `OutOfMemoryException`

This code works great for small data:

```
// WebClient ------------------------------------------------------------------
var _client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var _content = _client.DownloadString(_url);
```

but blows up on the last line (`DownloadString`)

I tried changing to this which also works for small data but it still blew up on the `ReadToEnd` line when the data grew in size.

```
using (var _response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream _dataStream = _response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader _streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(_dataStream))
        {
            string _responseFromServer = _streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I tried this which worked:

```
StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (var _response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream _dataStream = _response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader _streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(_dataStream))
        {
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                char[] _buffer = new char[4096];
                _streamReader.ReadBlock(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
                var _bufferString = new String(_buffer);
                _stringBuilder.Append(_bufferString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it blew up with an `OutOfMemoryException` error when it got to the next line here:

```
var _results = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(_stringBuilder.ToString());
```

It didn't like the `ToString()` method.

It also crashed with a simple line like

```
string _convertedString = _stringBuilder.ToString();
```

The full error is:

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

The machine is running 64bit windows with 16Gb of memory.

So, what are my options?

All I want is an `IQueryable<MyObject>` from a (very large) `JSON` string.

Comment: Check out the answer for this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315521/system-outofmemoryexception-with-json-net-with-listobject, deserializes one object at a time

Comment: An OutOfMemoryException can occur for various reasons, eg exhausting buffers, GDI objects etc. The exception's call stack will tell you where that occured, but the real culprit is inefficent code. *WHY* are you using a StringBuilder when you can read the data through a StreamReader? What you are doing isn't any better (or more efficient) than a `streamReader.ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - those are just the various methods I've tried to get this to work just to show the processes. If there was a way to get the value in the StreamReader into the  Deserializer without the memory error then I would love to know.

Comment: If you create [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be easier for us to see the problem.

Comment: @dbugger - I didn't see that one. Never knew you could deserialize one item at a time. I will give it a go and see if that works. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code essentially emulates what [StreamReader.ReadToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx) does, taking at least 4 times the memory needed to read a large response (the memory of the string response itself, the StringBuilder's internal buffer, the size of all the intermediate temporary strings and the final string).

You can avoid this by deserializing from the stream directly with a JsonTextReader. Copying from the [documentation sample](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm):

```
using (var json= new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    return (List<MyObject>)serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(List<MyObject>));
}
```

O

Comment: perfect! worked a treat first time - just a minor change to your code - changed the word file to jsonTextReader