# Combine Multiple JSON Files Json.NET

Tags: json.net

I have an API that currently receives JSON calls that I push to files (800KB-1MB) (1 for each call), and would like to have an hourly task that takes all of the JSON files in the last hour and combines them into a single file as to make it better to do daily/monthly analytics on.

Each file consists of a collection of data, so in the format of [ object {property: value, ... ].  Due to this, I cannot do simple concatenation as it'll no longer be valid JSON (nor add a comma then the file will be a collection of collections).  I would like to keep the memory foot-print as low as possible, so I was looking at the following [example](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/14/writing-json-to-a-file-using-json-net) and just pushing each file to the stream (deserializing the file using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileContent); however, by doing this, I end up with a collection of collection as well.  I have also tried using a JArray instead of the JsonConvert, pushing to a list outside of the foreach with but provides the same result.  If I move the Serialize call outside the ForEach, it does work; however, I am worried about holding the 4-6GB worth of items in memory.

In summary, I'm ending up with [ [ object {property: value, ... ],... [ object {property: value, ... ]] where my desired output would be [ object {property: value (file1), ... object {property: value (fileN) ].

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\combined.json", FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    jw.Formatting = Formatting.None;

                    JArray list = new JArray();
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                    foreach (IListBlobItem blob in blobContainer.ListBlobs(prefix: "SharePointBlobs/"))
                    {
                        if (blob.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                        {
                            var blockBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)blob;
                            var content = blockBlob.DownloadText();
                            var deserialized = JArray.Parse(content);
                            //deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
                            list.Merge(deserialized);
                            serializer.Serialize(jw, list);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Non-Block-Blob: " + blob.StorageUri);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, to keep your processing and memory footprints low, I think I would just concatenate the files one after the other even though it results in technically invalid JSON.  To deserialize the combined file later, you can take advantage of the `SupportMultipleContent` setting on the `JsonTextReader` class and process the object collections through a stream as if they were one whole collection.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32237819/10263) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: That looks exactly what I need -  I am surprised this issue is as common enough that they actually made that setting!  Thank you.

Comment: I was also surprised when I first came across it, but it has come in handy more than once.