# JSON DeserializeObject is very slow

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I created small recursive C# app to parse unknown JSON string to find particular Key/Value pair's using `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`. It works OK on small JSON strings, but takes really long time, if JSON is bigger: 3.5MB JSON file with 15K+ lines takes >3 min to parse. Parsing same file using RegExp takes <1 sec. Is that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` takes that long ?!

```
    string json = @"{""origin-of_error"" : ""error_message"",""foo"" : ""bar""}";
    static void GetJsonValue (string json, string findStr = "foo")
    {
        try
        {

            if (Regex.Match(json, @"^\[", RegexOptions.Multiline).Success)
            {
                // JSON string Array []
                var jArr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(json);
                foreach (var jLine in jArr) GetJsonValue(jLine.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                // JSON string KEY:VALUE
                var jLog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, Object>>(json);               
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> jEntry in jLog)
                {
                    if (jEntry.Key.ToString() == findStr) Console.WriteLine("MATCH:" +  jEntry.ToString());
                    GetJsonValue(jEntry.Value.ToString());
                }                       
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: You can't compare a Regex match with creating objects, it's an order of magnitude more complicated. Have you a question are is this just a rant in disguise?

Comment: Note that you're parsing the JSON many, many times here too. Why not parse it *once* to a `JObject` and then look through that recursively?

Comment: That was easiest way. Was not expecting such time consuming.

Comment: 1) Have you tried to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927) your app?  What did you find?  2) You should not load a 3.5MB text file into a single string, see [Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm).  3) It looks like you are using huge amounts of intermediate memory for JTokens and strings.  Instead, consider adopting the approach of [Parsing large json file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227436).  You will need to test whether the root is an array or object and adapt accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I learned array versus object in hard way. Thank You, k

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what your problem is since you don't include a sample of your actual JSON, however it appears you are trying to sequentially deserialize the values in large a JSON array, or the values of the key/value pairs in a large JSON object, when stored in a file on disk.

That being said, some recommendations can be made:

1. Rather than loading the JSON into a large (3.5 MB) string, you should stream directly from the file, as is explained in [Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm).
2. Your current approach seems to be to deserialize to a large temporary `Dictionary<string, object>` or `List<object>`, then for each value, reserialize to a string, and deserialize that.  This will not be performant.

   If the values you are trying to deserialize are complex objects, you can adapt the solution from [Parsing large json file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227436/parsing-large-json-file-in-net), enhance to handle the fact that your root JSON container might be an array or object.

   Thus, instead, use:

   ```
   public static partial class JsonExtensions
   {
       public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeValues<T>(Stream stream)
       {
           return DeserializeValues<T>(new StreamReader(stream));
       }

       public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeValues<T>(TextReader textReader)
       {
           var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
           var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader);
           reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
               {
                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                       if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
                           continue; // Do nothing
                       else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
                           break; // Break from the loop
                       else
                           yield return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
                   }
               }
               else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
               {
                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                       if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
                           continue; // Do nothing
                       else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                           continue; // Eat the property name
                       else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject)
                           break; // Break from the loop
                       else
                           yield return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. If the values you are trying to deserialize are *primitives* (i.e. just strings, as is shown in your example), then you should skip deserializing entirely, and read them directly.  Deserializing requires creation and processing of a [data contract](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm), usually through reflection.  Reading directly skips this complexity.

   Thus you could do:

   ```
   public static partial class JsonExtensions
   {
       public static bool IsPrimitive(this JsonToken tokenType)
       {
           switch (tokenType)
           {
               case JsonToken.Integer:
               case JsonToken.Float:
               case JsonToken.String:
               case JsonToken.Boolean:
               case JsonToken.Undefined:
               case JsonToken.Null:
               case JsonToken.Date:
               case JsonToken.Bytes:
                   return true;
               default:
                   return false;
           }
       }

       public static IEnumerable<string> ReadPrimitives(Stream stream)
       {
           return ReadPrimitives(new StreamReader(stream));
       }

       public static IEnumerable<string> ReadPrimitives(TextReader textReader)
       {
           var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader);
           reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               if (reader.TokenType.IsPrimitive())
               {
                   if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
                       yield return reader.Value.ToString(); // No need for conversion
                   else
                       yield return (string)JValue.Load(reader); // Convert to string.
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

For both #2 and #3, you would pass the `Stream` or `StreamReader` created by opening your file on disk.