# Take 1gb ram to parse json object and give System.OutOfMemoryException after performing any other filter

Tags: c#, json.net

```
public void ReadJsonFile()
{
    try
    {
        string json = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(val))
        {
            json = r.ReadToEnd();
            var test = JObject.Parse(json);
            JArray items = (JArray)test["locations"];
            int length = items.Count;

            data = new List<Info>();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                var d = test["locations"][i]["timestampMs"];
                double dTimeSpan = Convert.ToDouble(d);
                DateTime dtReturn = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(Math.Round(dTimeSpan / 1000d)).ToLocalTime();
                string printDate = dtReturn.DayOfWeek.ToString() + "," + " " + dtReturn.ToShortDateString() + " " + dtReturn.ToShortTimeString();
                day = dtReturn.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                date = dtReturn.ToShortDateString();
                time = dtReturn.ToShortTimeString();
                var e = test["locations"][i]["latitudeE7"];
                var f = test["locations"][i]["longitudeE7"];
                var n = test["locations"][i]["accuracy"];
                accuracy = n.ToString();
               // getLocationByGeoLocation(e.ToString(), f.ToString());                   
                var g = test["locations"][i]["activity"] != null;
                if (g == true)
                {
                    JArray items1 = (JArray)test["locations"][i]["activity"];
                    int length1 = items1.Count;
                    while (j < items1.Count)
                    {
                        if (j == 0)
                        {
                            var h = test["locations"][i]["activity"][j]["activity"][j]["type"];
                            type = h.ToString();
                            j = 1;
                        }
                        else { }
                        j++;
                    }
                    j = 0;
                }
                else { }

                Info ddm = new Info(day, date, time, lat, longi, address, accuracy, type);
                data.Add(ddm);
                type = "";
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse JSON file. val is the name of my file to parse. Using StreamReader I am reading each line when I am trying to parse using jObject I will take around 1gb memory and give me System.OutOfMemoryException how can I parse JObject using small memory.
Please help me with this I don't have much idea of JSON.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `JsonReader`

Comment: Can you give an example, please

Comment: How big is the file you are trying to read?

Comment: Firstly, get rid of `json = r.ReadToEnd()` and stream directly from the file using [`JObject.Load(JsonReader)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Load.htm).  You're allocating a gigantic string unnecessarily.  Then see where you stand.

Comment: 150 MB but it has more than 2 lakh rows

Comment: Like @dbc mentioned for a big file, instead of allocating everything in one go, stream from the file

Comment: Next, why are you loading to an intermediate `JToken` hierarchy at all?  Why not deserialize directly to an appropriate data model?  Switching to direct deserialization will save lots of intermediate memory.

Comment: Finally, if you still can't load the file using deserialization, you'll need to adopt a piecemeal stream technique like the one shown in [Parsing large json file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32227436) and [How to parse huge JSON file as stream in Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43747477/3744182).  But before doing that, first get rid of the intermediate objects `json` and `test`.

Comment: I don't have much idea about JSON file I take this code from the net but I work for a small file.

Comment: @user10753256 Could you please past an example of json data you are trying to parse?

Comment: {
  "locations" : [ {
    "timestampMs" : "1521958808759",
    "latitudeE7" : 196590799,
    "longitudeE7" : 727169204,
    "accuracy" : 2299
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1521956972681",
    "latitudeE7" : 196617374,
    "longitudeE7" : 727147037,
    "accuracy" : 2400
  },}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read about JSON thoroughly. NewtonSof.JSON is are very famous library and it is well documented. Let us get back to your problem. As mentioned in comments you have lots of unnecessary middle steps while trying to parse your file. Moreover, you are trying to parse a big file in one go!. First thing first, this is the layout for your JSON

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("locations")]
    public Location[] Locations { get; set; }
}

public partial class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("timestampMs")]
    public string TimestampMs { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("latitudeE7")]
    public long LatitudeE7 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("longitudeE7")]
    public long LongitudeE7 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("accuracy")]
    public long Accuracy { get; set; }
}
```

And while you are deserilazing you should do it object by object, not all at once
The following assumes that your `stream` is made of `Data` type of objects, if it is, made up of `Location` type of objects you have to change it

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(val))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            var data = serializer.Deserialize<Data>(reader);
            //data.locations etc etc..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine but how can I apply  JArray items = (JArray)test["locations"];
            int length = items.Count;and get value from  loop through

Comment: Do you want to get the size of the Locations array

Comment: Yes because I am converting timestamp and all four things so use loop for that like in my previous code JArray items = (JArray)test["locations"];
            int length = items.Count;

Comment: Then please use `data.Locations.Length`. Please let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: Ya, thank you so much it works.

Comment: How can i get this value var h = test["locations"][i]["activity"][j]["activity"][j]["type"];  because now every time i get 0 as a value o type

Comment: You don't need to use i or j as indexes. Look at the class properties then you can access them

Comment: "timestampMs" : "1521949958568",
    "latitudeE7" : 196616755,
    "longitudeE7" : 727194779,
    "accuracy" : 2496,
    "activity" : [ {
      "timestampMs" : "1521949958783",
      "activity" : [ {
        "type" : "STILL",
        "confidence" : 100
      } ]
    } ]  I want this type from activity how can i get using your code

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the System.OutOfMemoryException with the following steps:

If you are not using Visual Studio Hosting Process:

Uncheck the option:

```
Project->Properties->Debug->Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process
```

if still the problem remains:

Go to Project->Properties->Build Events->Post-Build Event Command line and paste this 2 lines

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\..\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x86
"$(DevEnvDir)..\..\vc\bin\EditBin.exe" "$(TargetPath)"  /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
```

Now, build the project