# Need to run LINQ queries on several hundred JSON files in child folders

Tags: c#, linq-to-json

Using c#:

I have a few hundreds of JSON files in nested folders in file system. 
I need to run LINQ queries within the data in files and find the JSON files that their JSON data matches certain crieria.

I can simly serialize all the JSON files in a List, then run my LINQ query on the array. However the approach takes lots of memory since I am reading all data from disk.

Is there any way to run my LINQ query on JSON files in file system without loading all of them in memory?

Comment: Do you need to process them all at once?

Comment: I jsut need to run query on them. For example give me list of productName with create date in Aug 2016.

Comment: It is somewhat hard to write code that behaves the way you describe - normally one would `foreach(var item in GetAllItemsWithLinq()){ item...}` which does not need to load more than one item at a time... Some clarification why such approach does not work in your case may narrow down the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to stream the data as described in the following posts or something similar.  This should help with the memory issues.
[How to parse huge JSON file as stream in Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747477/how-to-parse-huge-json-file-as-stream-in-json-net), 
[Parsing large json file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227436/parsing-large-json-file-in-net)

Comment: I think my senario is diffrent. I have 900 small files. You are refering to one large file.

Comment: You could still read each file/object individually, run your validation/analysis on it, then put whatever information into a separate List<T> that you're tracking.  At least that's how I was thinking of it.  Doing it this way doesn't allow you to run a LINQ statement against ALL the objects at once, but you wouldn't have to put it all into memory at once.

Comment: yes, and this is something that @Alexei Levenkov suggested

Answer (score 0):

Ok noSql will not work for you, but here i found a diffrent solution that you could use.

Insert the files in sql db then you could simply do a select stats on them.

Here is an one way of doing it

```
-- Load file contents into a variable
SELECT @json = BulkColumn
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\JSON\Books\book.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j

-- Load file contents into a table 
SELECT BulkColumn
 INTO #temp 
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\JSON\Books\book.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
```

And using Json_Value to read

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo,'$.info.address[0].town') AS Town
FROM #temp
WHERE JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo,'$.info.address[0].state') LIKE 'US%'
ORDER BY JSON_VALUE(jsonInfo,'$.info.address[0].town')
```

Here is how to import json files

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

And here is how to do a where sats in them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: That is diffrent application architecture. For my requirments, the JSON files need to stay in file system along with other files.

Comment: Do you know any no sql library that I can have a DB consistes of JSON files scattered on file system?

Comment: Updated my answer, read it and let me know if it work for you. its not exactly linq

Comment: Thank you for the update. The problem is that this completely changes the problem definition. I wanted to find if there is a good technique to do this in C# and you are adding a relatively big component (SQL Server) to the solution.

Comment: not sql server but sqllite will also work https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html. and here is also EntityWorker.Core it support sqllite. and here https://sqlitebiter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/usage/file/ you can import json file into sqllite