# Read the JSON incrementally from API. Error: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content

Tags: c#, json, stream, deserialization, httpclient

I need to open a connection to an API, keep it open and read JSON data incrementally from the open connection.
JSON looks like this:

```
{"type":"PRICE","time":"2020-02-06T16:11:55.724311939Z","bids":[{"price":"1.09730","liquidity":10000000}],"asks":[{"price":"1.09741","liquidity":10000000}],"closeoutBid":"1.09730","closeoutAsk":"1.09741","status":"tradeable","tradeable":true,"instrument":"EUR_USD"}{"type":"PRICE","time":"2020-02-06T16:11:58.619901113Z","bids":[{"price":"1.09731","liquidity":10000000}],"asks":[{"price":"1.09742","liquidity":10000000}],"closeoutBid":"1.09731","closeoutAsk":"1.09742","status":"tradeable","tradeable":true,"instrument":"EUR_USD"}{"type":"PRICE","time":"2020-02-06T16:12:00.095991323Z","bids":[{"price":"1.09730","liquidity":10000000}],"asks":[{"price":"1.09741","liquidity":10000000}],"closeoutBid":"1.09730","closeoutAsk":"1.09741","status":"tradeable","tradeable":true,"instrument":"EUR_USD"}
```

Every 250mseconds comes a block of data but I am able to read and display only the first block of data, after which I get the error: "Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content"

The code I have until now:

```
        private async Task IncrementalDeserializeFromStreamCallAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APP_VERSION", "1.0.0");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "tokentokentoken");
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/101-004-4455670-001/pricing/stream?instruments=EUR_USD"))

        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken))
        {
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                    {
                        // Load each object from the stream and do something with it
                        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
                        Console.WriteLine(obj);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to set `SupportMultipleContent` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32237819/3744182) to [Parsing large JSON file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32227436/3744182) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729419/3744182) to [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063/3744182).  In fact this looks to be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Yes, Thank you . Adding "reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;" solved the problem.