How to parse large json file in c# to avoid Out of memory exception
I have json file stored in text file which is of size 40 GB+.I am using below code which is throwing Out of memory exception. Is there any way we can take part by part of text file and parse ,something similar to big XML like (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader) in this scenario
Small snippet of Json is like as below
{
  "networkElementPath": "Test_site_ns1 > ns1_N2_B",
  "recordTypeName": "RAN5G_Cell",
  "collectionTimeEpoch": 1713520800,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "DL PRB Average Utilization dnum",
      "value": 5110563822,
      "type": "DOUBLE",
      "unit": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "UL PRB Average Utilization dnum",
      "value": 1375920000,
      "type": "DOUBLE",
      "unit": ""
    }
  ]
}
{
  "networkElementPath": "Test_site_ns2 > ns2_N2_B",
  "recordTypeName": "RAN5G_Cell",
  "collectionTimeEpoch": 1713520800,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "DL PRB Average Utilization dnum",
      "value": 5110563822,
      "type": "DOUBLE",
      "unit": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "UL PRB Average Utilization dnum",
      "value": 1375920000,
      "type": "DOUBLE",
      "unit": ""
    }
  ]
}
..............etc

and code to used  to parse is as below
    class Program
    {
           JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        List<NetworkElement> o;
        using (FileStream s = File.Open(@"\\As21382dxbdb05\enrm\kafkafile\kafka.txt", FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                o = serializer.Deserialize<List<NetworkElement>>(reader);
            }
        }

  public class NetworkElement
    {
        public string networkElementPath { get; set; }
        public string recordTypeName { get; set; }
        public string collectionTimeEpoch { get; set; }
        public List<Data> lstData { get; set; }
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public string name;
        public double value;
        public string type;
        public string unit;
    }


Yes, there are already questions on exactly this topic, see How to parse huge JSON file as stream in Json.NET? and Parsing large JSON file in .NET.  Do those answer your question?

Also, is your file actually JSON, or is it a sequence of top-level JSON objects without an outer array container?  If so you need to read it like a line-delimited JSON file as shown in Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing.

@dbc it is coming through a kafka stream like above and i am getting by using confluent.kafka and saving to a text file

Sorry, I don't know what a kafka stream is, I'm working in .NET.  A well-formed JSON file as per RFC 8259 consists of a single root token, generally an array or object.  Does your JSON consist of a single root token (e.g. an array), or a sequence of top-level objects?  The fact that there is no comma between the two objects suggests that it's the latter.  Is that correct?

@dbc  when i used code mentioned in link  How to parse huge JSON file as stream in Json.NET? i am getting error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MNOSSIntegration.NetworkElement]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly

@dbc you are correct ,there is no comma, will that make issues? Actually we are reading from remote team

If there is no comma between objects, it isn't actually a well-formed JSON file, it's a sequence of JSON objects, so you need to use SupportMultipleContent = true as shown in Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing.  Otherwise the code from How to parse huge JSON file as stream in Json.NET? works, you just need to deserialize to do var network = serializer.Deserialize<NetworkElement>(reader);, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/rn01mR.

Json.NET can read a sequence of JSON objects with no comma by setting JsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent.  (System.Text.Json does not support it though.)  In fact JsonExtensions.FromDelimitedJson<NetworkElement>(TextReader, JsonSerializerSettings ) from this answer should work for you as-is.

@dbc i did reader.SupportMultipleContent = true; ,but still getting error Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type '.Generic.List`1NetworkElement]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

@dbc i have edited my question with sample code i used

Your JSON tokens are objects not arrays of objects so you need to use o = serializer.Deserialize<LNetworkElement>(reader) as shown in https://dotnetfiddle.net/rn01mR.   You also need [JsonProperty("data")]  on public List<Data> lstData Anyway, is this complex enough that you need an answer, or is this comment thread enough?

Your question is currently only about reading and parsing.  Where does File.WriteAllText() figure into it?  If you also are running out of memory when writing as well as when reading, please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

@dbc i got it,sorry, so far so good,i will update my result after all my experiment

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227436/parsing-large-json-file-in-net

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747477/how-to-parse-huge-json-file-as-stream-in-json-net
