# Deserialize [multiple] json array stream one item at a time from a file

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to read multiple json objects from a file. This is a very large file and I don't want to do read every character and check for braces. Any thoughts how this can be deserialized from file stream?

test.json

```
[{"name": "foo","id": 1},{"name": "bar","id": 2},{"name": "a","id": 3}]
[{"name": "foo","id": 1},{"name": "bar","id": 2},{"name": "a","id": 3}]
[{"name": "foo","id": 1},{"name": "bar","id": 2},{"name": "a","id": 3}]
```

Here's a solution for valid json file. [Deserialize json array stream one item at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374083/deserialize-json-array-stream-one-item-at-a-time/37039241#37039241)

Comment: What programming language are you trying to do this for?

Comment: Please tag it as such then, so that the question can be found more easily.

Comment: Is it a general question or you need solution for file with specific formatting? Because json file you show above can be parsed line by line without any problems. And if it IS a general question, well good luck.